# Firebase image upload, resize via cloud functions (https), and save to firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to achieve the following, however as a bit of a newbie, I can't see what I'm doing wrong:

1. File upload triggers a cloud function (https.onRequest())
2. Resize the image 3 times (100x100 thumb, 500x500 thumb, resize original to limit it's size)
3. Save all 3 images to the firebase storage bucket (Google Storage)
4. Get the respective signed URLs of the 3 images
5. Save signed URLs to Firestore

The following code works, but not consistently:

In my index.js file I create the HTTP trigger by: 
    `export const image = functions.https.onRequest(uploadImage);`

That calls:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as Busboy from "busboy";
import * as fs from "fs";
import * as os from "os";
import * as path from "path";
const cors = require("cors")({ origin: true });

const spawn = require("child-process-promise").spawn;

const gcconfig = {
  projectId: "PROJECT_ID",
  keyFilename: "key.json"
};
const gcs = require("@google-cloud/storage")(gcconfig);

export const uploadImage = (req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
    if (req.method === "POST") {
      const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
      const docRef = req.query.docRef;
      const fieldRef = req.query.fieldRef;
      const storageRef = req.query.storageRef;
      let fileData = null;

      // Max height and width of the thumbnail in pixels.
      const THUMB_MAX_HEIGHT = 100;
      const THUMB_MAX_WIDTH = 100;
      const THUMB_PREFIX = "thumb_";
      const RESIZED_MAX_HEIGHT = 500;
      const RESIZED_MAX_WIDTH = 500;
      const RESIZED_PREFIX = "resized_";
      const ORIGINAL_MAX_HEIGHT = 1000;
      const ORIGINAL_MAX_WIDTH = 1400;

      // Listen for event when Busboy finds a file to stream.
      busboy.on("file", (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
        const tempLocalFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filename);
        fileData = { file: filename, type: mimetype };

        // Download file local tmp.
        file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(tempLocalFile));
      });

      busboy.on("finish", () => {

        // File and directory paths.
        const tempLocalFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileData.file);
        const tempLocalThumbFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(),`${THUMB_PREFIX}${fileData.file}`);
        const tempLocalResizedFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(),`${RESIZED_PREFIX}${fileData.file}`);
        const origFilePath = path.normalize(path.join(storageRef, fileData.file));
        const thumbFilePath = path.normalize(path.join(storageRef, `${THUMB_PREFIX}${fileData.file}`));
        const resizedFilePath = path.normalize(path.join(storageRef, `${RESIZED_PREFIX}${fileData.file}`));

        // Cloud Storage files.
        const bucket = gcs.bucket("PROJECT_ID.appspot.com");
        const metadata = {
          contentType: fileData.type,
          "Cache-Control": "public,max-age=3600"
        };

        // Generate a thumbnail called tempLocalThumbFile
        const promise = spawn(
          "convert",
          [
            tempLocalFile,
            "-thumbnail",
            `${THUMB_MAX_WIDTH}x${THUMB_MAX_HEIGHT}>`,
            tempLocalThumbFile
          ],
          { capture: ["stdout", "stderr"] }
        );

        return promise
          .then(() => {
            // Generate a resized_ called tempLocalResizedFile
            return spawn(
              "convert",
              [
                tempLocalFile,
                "-thumbnail",
                `${RESIZED_MAX_WIDTH}x${RESIZED_MAX_HEIGHT}>`,
                tempLocalResizedFile
              ],
              { capture: ["stdout", "stderr"] }
            );
          })
          .then(() => {
            // Resize original to ensure it's not massive
            return spawn(
              "convert",
              [
                tempLocalFile,
                "-thumbnail",
                `${ORIGINAL_MAX_WIDTH}x${ORIGINAL_MAX_HEIGHT}>`,
                tempLocalFile
              ],
              { capture: ["stdout", "stderr"] }
            );
          })
          .then(() => {
            // upload images to storage
            const thumbUp = bucket.upload(tempLocalThumbFile, {
              destination: thumbFilePath,
              metadata: metadata
            });
            const resizeUp = bucket.upload(tempLocalResizedFile, {
              destination: resizedFilePath,
              metadata: metadata
            });
            const origUp = bucket.upload(tempLocalFile, {
              destination: origFilePath,
              metadata: metadata
            });

            return Promise.all([thumbUp, resizeUp, origUp]);
          })
          .then(() => {
            // Once the image has been uploaded delete the local files to free up disk space.
            fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalFile);
            fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalThumbFile);
            fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalResizedFile);

            const config = {
              action: "read",
              expires: "03-01-2500"
            };

            // Get the Signed URLs for the thumbnail and original image.
            return Promise.all([
              bucket.file(thumbFilePath).getSignedUrl(config),
              bucket.file(resizedFilePath).getSignedUrl(config),
              bucket.file(origFilePath).getSignedUrl(config)
            ]);
          })
          .then(results => {
            console.log("Got Signed URLs.", results);
            const thumbFileUrl = results[0][0];
            const resizeFileUrl = results[1][0];
            const origFileUrl = results[2][0];

            // Add the URLs to the Database
            return admin
              .firestore()
              .doc(docRef)
              .update({
                [fieldRef + ".original"]: origFileUrl,
                [fieldRef + ".resized"]: resizeFileUrl,
                [fieldRef + ".thumb"]: thumbFileUrl
              });
          })
          .then(() => {
            console.log("Image URLs saved to Firestore.");
            res.status(200).send({
              message: "File Saved."
            });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log("Error:", err);
            res.status(500).send({
              error: err
            });
          });
        });
      busboy.end(req.rawBody);
    } else {
      return res.status(500).json({
        message: "Not Allowed"
      });
    }
  });
};
```

The error message I receive when it fails is:

> Error: { ChildProcessError: `convert /tmp/ff658860-cc0f-11e8-bd7d-178b6a853dfe.png -thumbnail 100x100> /tmp/thumb_ff658860-cc0f-11e8-bd7d-178b6a853dfe.png` failed with code 1 at ChildProcess. (/user_code/node_modules/child-process-promise/lib/index.js:132:23) at emitTwo (events.js:106:13) at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7) at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16) at Socket. (internal/child_process.js:351:11) at emitOne (events.js:96:13) at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7) at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:509:12) name: 'ChildProcessError', code: 1, childProcess: ChildProcess { domain: Domain { domain: null, _events: [Object], _eventsCount: 1, _maxListeners: undefined, members: [] }, _events: { error: [Function: t], close: [Function] }, _eventsCount: 2, _maxListeners: undefined, _closesNeeded: 3, _closesGot: 3, connected: false, signalCode: null, exitCode: 1, killed: false, spawnfile: 'convert', _handle: null, spawnargs: [ 'convert', '/tmp/ff658860-cc0f-11e8-bd7d-178b6a853dfe.png', '-thumbnail', '100x100>', '/tmp/thumb_ff658860-cc0f-11e8-bd7d-178b6a853dfe.png' ], pid: 12, stdin: Socket { connecting: false, _hadError: false, _handle: null, _parent: null, _host: null, _readableState: [Object], readable: false, domain: [Object], _events: [Object], _eventsCount: 2, _maxListeners: undefined, _writableState: [Object], writable: false, allowHalfOpen: false, destroyed: true, _bytesDispatched: 0, _sockname: null, _pendingData: null, _pendingEncoding: '', server: null, _server: null, write: [Function: writeAfterFIN], _idleNext: null, _idlePrev: null, _idleTimeout: -1 }, stdout: Socket { connecting: false, _hadError: false, _handle: null, _parent: null, _host: null, _readableState: [Object], readable: false, domain: [Object], _events: [Object], _eventsCount: 4, _maxListeners: undefined, _writableState: [Object], writable: false, allowHalfOpen: false, destroyed: true, _bytesDispatched: 0, _sockname: null, _pendingData: null, _pendingEncoding: '', server: null, _server: null, read: [Function], _consuming: true, _idleNext: null, _idlePrev: null, _idleTimeout: -1, write: [Function: writeAfterFIN] }, stderr: Socket { connecting: false, _hadError: false, _handle: null, _parent: null, _host: null, _readableState: [Object], readable: false, domain: [Object], _events: [Object], _eventsCount: 4, _maxListeners: undefined, _writableState: [Object], writable: false, allowHalfOpen: false, destroyed: true, _bytesDispatched: 0, _sockname: null, _pendingData: null, _pendingEncoding: '', server: null, _server: null, read: [Function], _consuming: true, _idleNext: null, _idlePrev: null, _idleTimeout: -1, write: [Function: writeAfterFIN] }, stdio: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] }, stdout: '', stderr: 'convert: improper image header `/tmp/ff658860-cc0f-11e8-bd7d-178b6a853dfe.png\' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3927.\nconvert: no images defined`/tmp/thumb_ff658860-cc0f-11e8-bd7d-178b6a853dfe.png\' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.\n' }

I'm not familiar with busboy but believe I'm ending the process correctly, but as this typically only works for the first upload after saving the cloud function, I suspect the code may not be ending cleanly?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You kind of buried the significant output.  Looks like your input file is borked. >> stderr: 'convert: improper image header /tmp/ff658860-cc0f-11e8-bd7d-178b6a853dfe.png\' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3927.\nconvert: no images defined/tmp/thumb_ff658860-cc0f-11e8-bd7d-178b6a853dfe.png\'

Comment: Thanks Doug. Sorry bout that (it was my first time writing a question - I didn't know why SO formatted it differently to the other code).

It's strange. I hadn't noticed it was just doing it to a certain file - I'll test it out some more.

Does that mean there's no glaring mistakes in the function code?

Comment: I didn't check your code for errors (there's a lot of it), I just pointed you to the stated error.  Try doing something less complicated first, then add complexity to it as you see that the simpler parts are correct.

Comment: OK ta. I'll trim it all back and try to progressively build it. Thanks for the help!